# woocommerce product query (filter after attributes)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to make a wc_query that filters the products after an attribute but it does not work.

I tried many different ways, but here is one example that I tried:

```
        $product_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'pa_arbeitshohe',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => 20,
                            'operator' => '>'
                    )
            )
        );

        $products = wc_get_products( $product_args );
```

I'm sorry that some of the terms are in German, but I think that shouldn't make a difference. In this example I try to get every product, that has a "arbeitshohe" greater than 20. But the $products variable contains every product, even if the attribute "arbeitshohe" is not set for a product.
Here is a foto of how the attribute looks in the wordpress backend:

[woocommerce attribute in wordpress backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ST7m.png)

Is this even possible with queries?
Or is there another way I haven't even thought of?
Of course, I could also get all products and loop through them to sort some of them out, but I think writing a query is a much better way of filtering the products.

Or is there an even better way to handle custom attributes, in my opinion, the behavior for numeric attributes, where nearly every product has another value is a bit weird, because I have to predefine them before I can use them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be the best and easiest way to do it with a product filter plugin.

Why are you using `pa_arbeitshohe` ? When I take a look at your screenshot it just should be `arbeitshohe`.

Comment: I thought that I have to add the pa_ before the titleform. And it also worked for other attributes that are not numeric, so I think that should work.